# How recreate thread with new parameters?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium

I have multithreading program, which send email to my clients.
In my code: thread have some troubles - code just close window of firefox and that's it.
I want to create these algorithm: thread have some troubles - window of firefox (+selenium) just close(only one thread is closing, another threads should continue working), get another parameters data from my DB and start thread again with new parameters
And all of time should working 5-10 threads non-stop. If something goes wrong with thread - firefox window should be closed, program get another data from DB(i'll create these code, it's easy) and should open new firefox window and continue working with new parameters.

Main method:

```
static String path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\clients.txt";
static String path_ok = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\clients2.txt";
static Integer numberMail = 1; //id рассылки
static List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

YandexConfig config1 = new YandexConfig("login1", "password1", "cookies", port1);
YandexConfig config2 = new YandexConfig("login2", "password2", "cookies", port2);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
CompletableFuture.runAsync(new DoThread("thread 1", path, path_ok, numberMail, users, config1), executor);
CompletableFuture.runAsync(new DoThread("thread 2", path, path_ok, numberMail, users, config2), executor);
```

doThread:

```
class DoThread implements Runnable {
    private String threadName;
    private Integer numberMail;
    private String themeMessage = "Your order";
    private String messageDefault = "blabla";
    private final List<User> users;
    private final String fileWait;
    private final String fileOk;
    private final YandexConfig config;

    DoThread(String threadName, String fileWait, String fileOk, Integer numberMail, List<User> users, YandexConfig config) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
        this.fileWait = fileWait;
        this.fileOk = fileOk;
        this.numberMail = numberMail;
        this.users = users;
        this.config = config;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread #" + threadName + " started");

        while (true) {
        try {
                auth(threadName, config.login, config.password);
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                System.out.println("Something goes wrong");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
            //another a lot of strings of code
    }
}
```

Question is: how I can restart thread with new parameters based on my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to modify the parameters for the next thread. You need to supply setters for the data and then just start up another thread.

```
class DoThread implements Runnable {
    ...
    void setThreadName(String name) { ... }
    void setFileOK(String fileOK) { ... }
}

class UseDoThread {
    void f() {
        DoThread r = new DoThread(...);
        new Thread(r).start();
        ...
        r.setThreadName("?");
        r.setFileOK("I think so");
        new Thread(r).start();
}
```

However, **warning**: You would need to wait for the thread to finish before modifying the values and restarting. Otherwise, the first run will use the modified values and your data will be essentially corrupt. You can wait for the thread to finish in a number of wait, most simply by using the `join` method on it.

But if you can simply `join` it, then you might not be benefitting from making this multithreaded in the first place.

A better approach might be to make a new instance of `DoThread` and start that.

```
void f() {
    new Thread(new DoThread("thread1", ...)).start();
    new Thread(new DoThread("thread2", ...)).start();
}
```

It is for this type of reason that throwaway classes with `final` values are used more in concurrent programming. Each thread needs its own variant, and if they are all going at once it does not make sense to try to recycle this type of class. So you could declare all of the fields in `DoThread` to be final if you plan to create a new `DoThread` each time.